# unknown column 'guru.kode_guru' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

SELECT `jadwal_ajar`.`hari`, `jadwal_ajar`.`waktu`, jenjang.`nama_jenjang`, `jurusan`.`nama_jurusan`, `kelas`.`nama_kelas`, `mapel`.`nama_mapel`, guru.`nama_guru`
FROM jadwal_ajar,`guru`  , `jenjang` , `jurusan` , `kelas` , `mapel`
LEFT JOIN `jadwal_ajar` as a5 ON guru.kode_guru = a5.`kode_guru` 
LEFT JOIN `jadwal_ajar` as a1 ON `kelas`.`kode_kelas` = a1.`kode_kelas` 
LEFT JOIN `jadwal_ajar` as a2 ON `mapel`.`kode_mapel` = a2.`kode_mapel` 
LEFT JOIN `jadwal_ajar` as a3 ON j.`kode_jenjang` = a3.`kode_jenjang` 
LEFT JOIN `jadwal_ajar` as a4 ON `jurusan`.`kode_jurusan` = a4.`kode_jurusan`

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is because of a missing field in the table `guru`, you should check it out.

And, from what I can see, I think that you are trying to join tables in the from, here is the way to achieve that:

```
SELECT jadwal_ajar.hari, jadwal_ajar.waktu, 
       jenjang.nama_jenjang, jurusan.nama_jurusan, kelas.nama_kelas, 
       mapel.nama_mapel, guru.nama_guru 
FROM jadwal_ajar
LEFT JOIN guru ON guru.kode_guru = jadwal_ajar.kode_guru 
LEFT JOIN kelas ON kelas.kode_kelas = jadwal_ajar.kode_kelas 
LEFT JOIN mapel ON mapel.kode_mapel = jadwal_ajar.kode_mapel 
LEFT JOIN jenjang ON jenjang.kode_jenjang = jadwal_ajar.kode_jenjang 
LEFT JOIN jurusan ON jurusan.kode_jurusan = jadwal_ajar.kode_jurusan
```